# Backbone Custom Collection Sync Cross Domain

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm currently using this custom sync in my backbone app which is working alright with local api url but when I change the LIVE api url it throws me 403 Forbidden error on ajax request. I know its cross domain issue so tried adding response header to my backend api which is in zend framework controller. And also tried adding response header to my htaccess file but it doesn't make any change... Here is the backbone collection script..

```
var CarsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Car,
        url: function(){
            return "http://example.com/api/salesrecord/";
        },
        parse: function(resp, xhr)
        {
            return resp.salesrecord;
        },
        sync: function(method, model, options) {
            var that = this;
            var params = _.extend({
                url: that.url,
                dataType: 'jsonp', //jsonp also not working..
                processData: false
            }, options);

            return $.ajax(params);
        }
    });
```

Response headers:

PHP:
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

HTACCESS
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I can see that url() is function, should it be { url: that.url() ...} there.

Comment: Open development tools and copy and paste exact information on error, including headers of request and response, that would help to sort that out.